# Upgrade Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.0 Resolving dependencies through SAT

Tags: composer, magento2.2.6, magento2.3.0

I am trying to update my Magento CE 2.2.6 to CE 2.3 with composer but am getting the following.

```
Reading C:/Users/garry/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-php-cs-fixer$diff.json from cache

Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #1800)
```

The pass counter keeps counting up and I have left it overnight but it does not finish, now it's been going for over an hour.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html).

I think it has something to do with `friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1`. I have tried installing it separately but with no luck.

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/magento2ce",
    "description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.4",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0",
        "magento/data-migration-tool": "2.2.4",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.0",
        "msp/recaptcha": "2.0.0",
        "faonni/module-indexer-url-rewrite": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.10.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2"
    },
    "extra": {
        "component_paths": {
            "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
            "components/jquery": [
                "lib/web/jquery.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
            ],
            "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
            "components/jqueryui": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
            ],
            "twbs/bootstrap": [
                "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
            ],
            "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com"
        },
        "data-migration-tool": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's something wrong within Composer. Either it should be able to resolve your dependencies or it should show you the conflicts it cannot resolve.It should not hang that long. Also see the thread here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7665

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Composer issue, not a Magento issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I used PHP 7.2.4 rather than 7.1.24 for the composer update it worked correctly.